# if and elseif json, angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular

right now i'm trying to finish  a task in our project . to explain  the situation i have field with iteams im must choose an iteam then another field appear and must choose again other  elements. those  element i  want to send them using json 
for exemple:
base:'the element of the first field'
headers:'the elements ot the  second field'.
when i use if and  else  if the operation stop after if and i dont know why.
this is the code i used[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0XzL.png).
thanks a lot of any help .

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. And, never post links to pictures of code. Post the actual code.

Comment: please not use an image to put your code, write it here

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to just to implement ***ngIf** Directory

Like I write example code below of button example

```
<input type="button" (click)="textBox=false">
<input type="text" placeholder="enter text" *ngIf="!textBox">
```

And if you again get problem after this code then please post sample code...

**Thanks**